# IGCSE - In general how the bits are read from a register

Tags: computer-science, cpu-registers

I'm just a beginner and trying to read IGCSE -computer science book. Here I got stuck in the following question. I don't have a tutor and I'm reading it out of interest, so please help me out.

In an automated vacuum cleaner, functions of two motors are interpreted from bits in 8-bit register.

[image]

now the question is, what will happen if the register contains the value 11111111?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on how the motor drivers are implemented.

In general mutual exclusive states are reflected at software level, i.e. instead of having a bit for *Motor B On* and one for *Motor B Off* we only have one bit for *Motor B On/Off*.
Though is not unusual to have an hardware interface that allow invalid states (like the all ones here) and rely on the software to always keep a consistent state.

What would happen if such a contract is violated can range from doing nothing to damaging the hardware (mechanically or electrically) passing through creating a race condition on the selected function (i.e. turning the motor on/off).

When you see an interface that allows for invalid states you have to think of it as a compromise: the designers made the hardware simpler at the cost of making the software slightly more complex.  As such you should consider the hardware "very sensitive" and avoid all the invalid states.
If you are curious about the specific behavior of an invalid state, you need to look at the schematic of the hardware or its datasheet.